# income_amount (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT SUM(income_amount) FROM INCOME WHERE month = '24'

Tags: java, android, sqlite, compiler-errors, android-sqlite

This is my first app and I'm having lots of problems I'm trying to use this code total all the income transactions for a month by comparing month field to month now but I get the above error code. No idea what to do. Code below.

```
 //Create Table Income
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_INCOME = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INCOME
        + "(" + COL_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL_INCOME_SOURCE + "TEXT,"
        + COL_INCOME_AMOUNT + "NUMERIC," + COL_ACCOUNT_TYPE + "TEXT," + COL_DATE + "DATE," +
        COL_DESCRIPTION + "TEXT," + COL_MONTH + "NUMERIC)";
```

**Method**

```
public double income_month(double month_income) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int month_now = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH + 1);
    SQLiteDatabase mDatabaseManager = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = mDatabaseManager.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(income_amount) FROM " +
            TABLE_INCOME + " WHERE " + COL_MONTH  + " = '" + month_now+ "'", null);

    if (c!=null)
    c.moveToFirst();
    do {
        assert c != null;
        month_income = c.getDouble(0);
    }
    while (c.moveToNext());
    c.close();

    return month_income;
}
```

**And the call in main activity**

```
 double month_income = 0;
        mDatabase = new DatabaseManager(this.getApplicationContext());
        month_income = mDatabase.income_month(month_income);
        final TextView incomeview = findViewById(R.id.income);
        incomeview.setText("" + month_income);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `CREATE` statement is wrong because there are no spaces between the column names and their data types.
Change to this:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_INCOME = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INCOME
        + "(" + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL_INCOME_SOURCE + " TEXT,"
        + COL_INCOME_AMOUNT + " NUMERIC," + COL_ACCOUNT_TYPE + " TEXT," + COL_DATE + " DATE," + COL_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT," + COL_MONTH + " NUMERIC)";
```

You will have to uninstall the app from the device so the database is deleted and rerun to recreate the table with the correct column names and data types.

Also use the constants for column names everywhere in the code to avoid mistakes, so instead of `income_amount` use `COL_INCOME_AMOUNT` and use `?` placeholders to pass parameters in `rawQuery()` instead of concatenating single quotes:

```
Cursor c = mDatabaseManager.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(" + COL_INCOME_AMOUNT + ") FROM " + TABLE_INCOME + " WHERE " + COL_MONTH  + " = ?", new String[] {month_now});
```

Comment: Thanks I've corrected with your suggestions and I no longer receive that error, however it doesn't actually total anything.

Comment: I don't know your data or the value of the parameter `month_now` that you pass so I can't tell. My answer is about the error that you got. If you have a new issue then you should post  a new question where you explain the problem.